# How create Facebook session with extended permission

Tags: java, android, facebook

How to create facebook session with extended permission in facebook sdk 3.0 for android?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

u have to first login the user. then when u need to extend permission do as: (i have used this for publish permission)

```
private static final List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("publish_actions");
private static final int REAUTH_ACTIVITY_CODE = 100;
// Check for publish permissions    
List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();
if (!isSubsetOf(PERMISSIONS, permissions)) {
    Session.ReauthorizeRequest reauthRequest = new Session
           .ReauthorizeRequest(this, PERMISSIONS)
           .setRequestCode(REAUTH_ACTIVITY_CODE);
    session.reauthorizeForPublish(reauthRequest);
    return;
}
```

`isSubsetOf()`:

```
private boolean isSubsetOf(Collection<String> subset, Collection<String> superset) {
  for (String string : subset) {
     if (!superset.contains(string)) {
         return false;
     }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use the facebook [LoginButton](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/LoginButton/) provided by the SDK (version 3.0), it will handle most of the session management for you and you can easily request permissions like this:

```
 authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("user_location", 
                               "user_birthday", "user_likes"));
```

Refer [the docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/fetch-user-data/) for a complete tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You can Set permission : Refer this [Graph api is not returning user email id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17081621/graph-api-is-not-returning-user-email-id/17082098#17082098)  And [Set permission for getting User's email ID from Facebook Login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16332283/set-permission-for-getting-users-email-id-from-facebook-login)