# Set permission for getting User's email ID from Facebook Login

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login, facebook-android-sdk

I'm using `Facebook 3.0 SDK` for android. I have to implement `Facebook` log in. I'm accessing user's basic info like name, userID. But I want to have access to email also of the user. I have gone through many blogs and forum but cannot figure out how to do that.

I'm using my own android button for log in not `com.facebook.widget.LoginButton`. If I use `Facebook` log in button it was easy just have to use these lines:

```
authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("basic_info","email"));
```

But, I have my own requirement, will have to go with default android buttons. Here is what I have done so far:

```
Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(
        this, Arrays.asList("email"));

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logIn);
    mLogin.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // start Facebook Login
    Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

        // callback when session changes state
        @Override
        public void call(final Session session, SessionState state,
                Exception exception) {
            if (session.isOpened()) {
                session.requestNewReadPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
                // make request to the /me API
                Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session,
                        new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                            // callback after Graph API response with user
                            // object
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user,
                                    Response response) {
                                if (user != null) {                         
                                    System.out
                                            .println("Facebook Response: "
                                                    + response.toString());
                                    access_token = session.getAccessToken();
                                    firstName = user.getFirstName();
                                    fb_user_id = user.getId();


                                    System.out
                                            .println("Facebook Access token: "
                                                    + access_token);
                                    System.out.println("First Name:"
                                            + firstName);
                                    System.out.println("FB USER ID: "
                                            + fb_user_id);


                                }
                            }
                        });
            }
        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode,
            resultCode, data);
}
```

I'm able to get all those things which I'm printing in log, but was unable to retrieve email from the user profile.

What can I do for this?

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: have you added the application information in the developer.facebook.com application page?

Comment: Yes, as you suggested I have added email in the permission in User & Friend Permissions. But no luck till now.

Comment: @Anupam Hello, have a look at this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30389180/facebook-oncompleted-email-java-lang-nullpointerexception

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Solved it: Here is what I have done...

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logIn);
    mLogin.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    Session currentSession = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (currentSession == null || currentSession.getState().isClosed()) {
        Session session = new Session.Builder(context).build();
        Session.setActiveSession(session);
        currentSession = session;
    }

    if (currentSession.isOpened()) {
        // Do whatever u want. User has logged in

    } else if (!currentSession.isOpened()) {
        // Ask for username and password
        OpenRequest op = new Session.OpenRequest((Activity) context);

        op.setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SUPPRESS_SSO);
        op.setCallback(null);

        List<String> permissions = new ArrayList<String>();
        permissions.add("publish_stream");
        permissions.add("user_likes");
        permissions.add("email");
        permissions.add("user_birthday");
        op.setPermissions(permissions);

        Session session = new Builder(MainActivity.this).build();
        Session.setActiveSession(session);
        session.openForPublish(op);
    }
}

public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (Session.getActiveSession() != null)
        Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode,
                resultCode, data);

    Session currentSession = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (currentSession == null || currentSession.getState().isClosed()) {
        Session session = new Session.Builder(context).build();
        Session.setActiveSession(session);
        currentSession = session;
    }

    if (currentSession.isOpened()) {
        Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

            @Override
            public void call(final Session session, SessionState state,
                    Exception exception) {

                if (session.isOpened()) {

                    Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session,
                            new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                                @Override
                                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user,
                                        Response response) {
                                    if (user != null) {

                                        TextView welcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcome);
                                        welcome.setText("Hello "
                                                + user.getName() + "!");

                                        access_token = session
                                                .getAccessToken();
                                        firstName = user.getFirstName();
                                        fb_user_id = user.getId();

                                        System.out
                                                .println("Facebook Access token: "
                                                        + access_token);
                                        System.out.println("First Name:"
                                                + firstName);
                                        System.out.println("FB USER ID: "
                                                + fb_user_id);

                                    }
                                }
                            });
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Now I'm able to get email permission with rest of the publish permission.

Marking this as accepted answer so that it can help others.

Comment: I attempted to set read permissions like this : `authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("email"));` and then tried to access the email like this `user.asMap().get("email")` but it always returns `null`.

Comment: Where we need to set FacebookAppId in this example?

Comment: In values/strings.xml as `appId`

Comment: Finally, I'm getting users email with this code, thanks. But Request.executeMeRequestAsync() is deprecated, you should call Request.newMeRequest().executeAsync() instead, although it executes the same code.

Comment: i used ur code to get user birthdate but i still have same problem get every thing but can't get birthdate any help??

Comment: I am trying to implement your code.but getting error at Session.which class or library you import for Session

Answer (score 3):

TL; DR: use something like this to get the email:

```
String email = (String) user.getProperty("email");
```

I have one comment about your code. Since "email" is a read permission, you don't need to create a separate permission request to get it. You can do something like this (code untested, so there might be slight errors):

```
Session s = new Session(this);
Session.setActiveSession(s);
Session.OpenRequest request = new Session.OpenRequest(this);
request.setPermissions(Arrays.asList("basic_info","email"));
request.setCallback( /* your callback here */ );
s.openForRead(request);
```

and you can get rid of the new permission request in your callback.

Comment: Were should I place this piece of code in my `MainActivity`? `String email = (String) user.getProperty("email");` is giving me null response.

Comment: You can put this in any activity.

Comment: As you can see I'm opening session on `onClick()`, so I need to put your piece of code inside that. And what will be here `request.setCallback( /* your callback here */ );`, what can be my callback? Please guide me through this. It will be very helpful for me.

Comment: Hey Ming, I have got the permission required for my app, but can you tell me why this is working only for `SUPPRESS_SSO` and not for `SSO_WITH_FALLBACK`.

Comment: Works perfectly. Simply use new Session.StatusCallback(){add unimplemented methods here} as a callback back (penultimate line)

Comment: Where we need to set FacebookAppId in this example?

Answer (score 0):

Use both buttons btnFbDesign, btnFbLogin (visibility GONE) in XML
then in btnFbDesign click listener use  binding.btnFbLogin.performClick()

```
 <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/btnFbDesign"
        style="@style/buttonStyle"
        android:layout_width="270dp"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/layer_facebook"
        android:paddingStart="20dp"
        android:paddingEnd="20dp"
        android:text="@string/continue_with_facebook"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/btnFbLogin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:alpha="0" />


 //facebook button
    binding.btnFbLogin.setOnClickListener {
        LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, listOf("public_profile"))
    }
    //read email permission
    binding.btnFbLogin.setPermissions("email")
    //custom design button click
    binding.btnFbDesign.setOnClickListener {
        //it will trigger btnFbLoin click
        binding.btnFbLogin.performClick()
    }
```