# Facebook user email is not accessible in some devices of Android for Facebook sdk 3.0

Tags: android, facebook

I integrated Facebook `SDK 3.0` in my app by following this [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/androidsdk/3.0/scrumptious/authenticate/). I am having one issue while getting email of the user.

For some device I am able to get the email but for some devices(Such as Samsung Note 2,Google Nexus of Samsung which I know right now.) I am not getting email.I already added permission for getting email.

Can anyone suggest me some guideline for this any type of help is appreciated.I am trying to get the user info in the following manner.

```
     Request request = Request.newMeRequest(session, 
            new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
            // If the response is successful
            if (session == Session.getActiveSession()) {

                if (user != null) {

                    String userName = user.getName();
                    String userEmail = user.asMap().get("email").toString();
                    userEmail = (String)user.getProperty("email");
                    String userId = user.getId();
                    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
                    String userAccessToken = session.getAccessToken();

                }
            }
            if (response.getError() != null) {

                // Handle errors, will do so later.
            }
        }
    });

String NAME = "name";
    String ID = "id";
    String PICTURE = "picture";
    String EMAIL = "email";
    String FIELDS = "fields";
    String REQUEST_FIELDS = TextUtils.join(",", new String[] {ID, NAME, PICTURE, EMAIL});

    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putString(FIELDS, REQUEST_FIELDS);
    request.setParameters(parameters);
    Request.executeBatchAsync(request);
```

I tried this also for getting email but still it is not working.

```
    Bundle params = request.getParameters();
    params.putString("fields", "email");
    params.putString("basic_info", "email,name");
    request.setParameters(params);
    Request.executeBatchAsync(request);
```

Any sort of help or guideline are helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I got the answer for my question I checked with one of my friend's `Facebook` id and found that he had not entered the his `Email Id` in his `Facebook` account.If we used permission for getting email still we don't get it because of this.For getting email we need to add permission which is mention in this [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/login-with-facebook/#step3) or we can explicitly add the permission as I used in my question.And one important thing is you can get email only if it mention over there.

Hope this could be helpful for some one.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should create an object of OpenRequest as shown on this link of Stack Overflow. It might solve your problem. :-
[Set permission for getting User's email ID from Facebook Login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16332283/set-permission-for-getting-users-email-id-from-facebook-login)

Comment: I already gone through this link but i want to use native login is it possible with this?