# My android app crashes when a user logs in to facebook

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I hope someone can help me.

I have an android app that has a standard login but also has twitter and facebook login buttons.

When the user try's to login using the facebook button the app crashes and I am unsure as to why? I believe that it is because the email field is returning as null.

I have rebuilt the app numerous times, the app is public on facebook, the app id is correct as is the package name.

logcat is below

```html
09-03 15:15:45.971  16896-17259/com.projects.bmxtrackfinder W/chromium﹕ [WARNING:keycode_converter.cc(91)] empty code string
09-03 15:15:47.470  16896-17259/com.projects.bmxtrackfinder W/chromium﹕ [WARNING:keycode_converter.cc(91)] empty code string
09-03 15:15:48.128  16896-17259/com.projects.bmxtrackfinder W/chromium﹕ [WARNING:keycode_converter.cc(91)] empty code string
09-03 15:15:52.942  16896-16896/com.projects.bmxtrackfinder W/BindingManager﹕ Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 16896
09-03 15:16:04.690  16896-16896/com.projects.bmxtrackfinder W/BindingManager﹕ Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 16896
09-03 15:16:04.821  16896-16896/com.projects.bmxtrackfinder E/SpannableStringBuilder﹕ SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
09-03 15:16:04.821  16896-16896/com.projects.bmxtrackfinder E/SpannableStringBuilder﹕ SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
09-03 15:16:04.828  16896-16896/com.projects.bmxtrackfinder E/SpannableStringBuilder﹕ SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
09-03 15:16:04.829  16896-16896/com.projects.bmxtrackfinder E/SpannableStringBuilder﹕ SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
09-03 15:16:05.094  16896-16896/com.projects.bmxtrackfinder E/FACEBOOK USERNAME**﹕ John TrackFinder
09-03 15:16:05.095  16896-16896/com.projects.bmxtrackfinder E/FACEBOOK ID**﹕ 135514753461349
09-03 15:16:05.096  16896-16896/com.projects.bmxtrackfinder E/FACEBOOK EMAIL**﹕ null
09-03 15:16:05.124  16896-17668/com.projects.bmxtrackfinder E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #4
    Process: com.projects.bmxtrackfinder, PID: 16896
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:304)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
            at com.fragments.activity.LoginActivity$2.onAsyncTaskDoInBackground(LoginActivity.java:263)
            at com.asynctask.MGAsyncTask.doInBackground(MGAsyncTask.java:45)
            at com.asynctask.MGAsyncTask.doInBackground(MGAsyncTask.java:10)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
09-03 15:16:05.667  16896-16896/com.projects.bmxtrackfinder E/WindowManager﹕ android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.fragments.activity.LoginActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{2f585567 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-729,192} that was originally added here
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:363)
            at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:271)
            at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:85)
            at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:298)
            at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:116)
            at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:99)
            at com.asynctask.MGAsyncTask.onPreExecute(MGAsyncTask.java:60)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:591)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:539)
            at com.fragments.activity.LoginActivity.syncFacebookUser(LoginActivity.java:274)
            at com.fragments.activity.LoginActivity$4.onCompleted(LoginActivity.java:423)
            at com.facebook.Request$1.onCompleted(Request.java:303)
            at com.facebook.Request$4.run(Request.java:1726)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
09-03 15:16:12.839  16896-16908/com.projects.bmxtrackfinder W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 11.292ms
```

(LoginActivity.java:263) = String email = user.asMap().get("email").toString;

Asynch code below:

```html
package com.asynctask;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

import com.projects.bmxtrackfinder.R;
import com.utilities.MGUtilities;

public class MGAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
   public ProgressDialog dialog;
   public Activity activity;
   public Object object;
   
   public int tag = 0;
   public int listTag = 0;
   
   OnMGAsyncTaskListener mCallback;
   
   public interface OnMGAsyncTaskListener {
        public void onAsyncTaskDoInBackground(MGAsyncTask asyncTask);
        public void onAsyncTaskProgressUpdate(MGAsyncTask asyncTask);
        public void onAsyncTaskPostExecute(MGAsyncTask asyncTask);
        public void onAsyncTaskPreExecute(MGAsyncTask asyncTask);
    }
   
   public void setMGAsyncTaskListener(OnMGAsyncTaskListener listener) {
      try {
            mCallback = (OnMGAsyncTaskListener) listener;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(this.toString() + "Did not implement OnMGAsyncTaskListener");
        }
   }
   
   public MGAsyncTask(Activity activity) {
      this.activity = activity;
   }
   
   public void startAsyncTask() {
      this.execute();
   }
   
   @Override
   protected String doInBackground(Void... params)  {
      mCallback.onAsyncTaskDoInBackground(this);
      return "";
   }
   
   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(String result)  {
      // execution of result of Long time consuming operation. parse json data
      dialog.dismiss();
      mCallback.onAsyncTaskPostExecute(this);
   }

   @Override
   protected void onPreExecute() {
      // Things to be done before execution of long running operation. For example showing ProgessDialog
        String loading = MGUtilities.getStringFromResource(activity, R.string.loading);
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(activity, "", loading, true);
      mCallback.onAsyncTaskPreExecute(this);
   }

   @Override
   protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
      // Things to be done while execution of long running operation is in progress. For example updating ProgessDialog
      mCallback.onAsyncTaskProgressUpdate(this);
   }
   
   public void setMessage(String message)  {
      dialog.setMessage(message);
   }
   
   public void setTitle(String title)  {
      dialog.setTitle(title);
   }
   
   public void setIcon(int resId)  {
      dialog.setIcon(resId);
   }
      
}
```

Comment: Add the entire Asynk Task code as well. The stacktrace points to an error in your DoInBackground part of the code. Please upload that as well.

Comment: Well, as you say, it looks like your `Map` doesn't have the key `"email"` for whatever reason.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook user email is not accessible in some devices of Android for Facebook sdk 3.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17419479/facebook-user-email-is-not-accessible-in-some-devices-of-android-for-facebook-sd)

Comment: uploaded the async code