# How to get email adress from Facebook PHP SDK?

Tags: php, facebook

Hi there i am currently working on Facebook login for my website.

For now i can display everything else like First name, Second name, ID of facebook member id but i can't not display the email.

Here is my php code:

```
<?php
require '../src/facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'MYIDDDDDD',
  'secret' => 'MYIDDDDDD',
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
  try {
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}
if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
  $statusUrl = $facebook->getLoginStatusUrl();
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'email'));
}
$naitik = $facebook->api('/naitik');

$myid = $user_profile['id'];
  $myemail = $user_profile['email'];
  echo $user_profile['first_name'];
  echo "Your id is - $myid<br>My email is = $myemail";
  $_SESSION['first_name']=$user_profile['first_name'];

?>
```

If it's important my App is in Sandbox mode.

Where is my mistake in this code and why `$myemail = $user_profile['email'];` is show as blank?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try removing it from sandbox mode after you have made the recommended change below.

Answer (score 1):

Did you first get the users permission to see his email?
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/email-permissions/
if not, see this post [Set permission for getting User's email ID from Facebook Login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16332283/set-permission-for-getting-users-email-id-from-facebook-login)