# Where to add permission in facebook me request?

Tags: android, facebook

I new to Facebook integration i want to get email id i know i have to add permission but dnt know where to add in this section ("Permission")

```
private class LoginDialogListener implements DialogListener {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "LoginONComplete");
                    String token = mFacebook.getAccessToken();
                    long token_expires = mFacebook.getAccessExpires();
                    Log.d(TAG, "AccessToken: " + token);
                    Log.d(TAG, "AccessExpires: " + token_expires);
                    sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager
                                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
                    sharedPrefs.edit().putLong("access_expires", token_expires)
                                    .commit();
                    sharedPrefs.edit().putString("access_token", token).commit();


                    edit.putString("toc", token);
                    edit.commit();




                    mAsyncRunner.request("me", new IDRequestListener());
            }
```

Comment: Check: [Set permission for getting User's email ID from Facebook Login](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16332283/set-permission-for-getting-users-email-id-from-facebook-login)

Comment: hi can you pelease tell me how to add permission in this link you have send to me is of diffrent structure