# cannot get user_birthday from facebook

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I having problem in the scenario of getting user_birthday from the Facebook, I have tried many solution and i found that i cannot get extra info from the first authentication logIn so I've created another request for getting user birthday and i tried many accepted solution 
like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16332283/set-permission-for-getting-users-email-id-from-facebook-login) 
but i still cannot get user email and the birthdate even when i tried to get age_range which is included in public_profile got nothing

and the facebook user is marked the birthdate as public 
i tried using sociauth library but with no success same problem

just i can get user birthday when i m using my account which is the dev of the app

finally i used `loginbutton` which is not my preferred scenario with permission

```
 authbutton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile","user_birthday"));
```

the wired thing is i can now get email without adding email permission but still get null with the birhtday and age_range

this is my loginbutton code

```
authbutton=(LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.authButton);
    authbutton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile","user_birthday"));
      // session state call back event
      authbutton.setSessionStatusCallback(new Session.StatusCallback() {
       @Override
       public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        if (session.isOpened()) {
                  Log.i("tag","Access Token"+ session.getAccessToken());
                  Request.newMeRequest(session,
                          new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                              @Override
                              public void onCompleted(GraphUser user,Response response) {
                                  if (user != null) {
                                   Log.i("tag","User ID "+ user.getId());
                                   Log.i("tag","Email "+ user.asMap().get("email"));
                                   lable.setText(user.getBirthday().toString());
                                  }
                              }
                          }).executeAsync();

              }

       }
     });
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: thanks but this is an old tutorial i want to use new api

Comment: use this may be you get the String birthday = user.getInnerJSONObject().getString("birthday");

Comment: Check : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user

Comment: @prakash i used this so i got no value for birthday

Comment: @HareshChhelana i checked it and even i cannot get the age_range which included in public_profile

Comment: first print this String,`system.out.println("dob:"+user.getInnerJSONObject());`,try it.

Comment: i got a json object which include evry thing beside birthday and age_range

Comment: have you checked that profile in public mode?

Comment: yes it is 
and the mail is just for friend and i can get it but the birhtday is public and i cant

Comment: use this permission string,  `private static final List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("user_groups","email","user_birthday","read_stream");`

Comment: sorry but same thing :(

Answer (score 1):

```
lable.setText(user.asMap().get("birthday").toString());
```

May be try this way?

The app id and the FB id you login to test should be of the same account. Else it will return null..