# Facebook login not returning email id

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I am got stucked, my facebook sdk not returning email id. i found that the problem is with v2.5.
its returning only id and name through graph user.

Any suggestion would be welcomed.
Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fetch not only email id, everything you can get.Here is code.

```
private CallbackManager callbackManager;
private LoginButton loginButton;
```

inside OnCreate() method

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
    loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
   // don't forget to give this.
   loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile,email,user_birthday"));
   loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getDetails();
        }
    });
   }
  private void getDetails() {
    //for facebook
    // FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    //register callback object for facebook result
    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

                    GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                            new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onCompleted(JSONObject jsonObject, GraphResponse graphResponse) {
                                    try {
                                        Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
                                        if (profile != null) {
                                           String facebook_id = profile.getId();
                                            String f_name = profile.getFirstName();
                                           String l_name = profile.getLastName();
                                            profile_image = profile.getProfilePictureUri(400, 400).toString();
                                        }
                                       String email_id = jsonObject.getString("email"); //email id
                                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                                        Logger.logError(e);
                                    }
                                }

                            });
```

Happy coding.

Comment: can you give me the sdk link to download facebook graph api. may be i am using older one.

Comment: you can download sdk from this link. i used in 4.0 https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android but almost 4.0.x will surely works. 2.5 is very older one. @PriyantaSingh

Comment: gradle used is com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0' use this which will surely works for above code.

Comment: Thanx @Shadow  your comment helped me alot.

Comment: glad to help you :) happy coding..@PriyantaSingh

Answer (score 0):

Have you set `permission` for `Email` to fetch email of user.
just see thease links [stackAnswer 01](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16332283/set-permission-for-getting-users-email-id-from-facebook-login)
and see some other permissions [here(FB link)](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions).

enjoy your code :)

Comment: yes . i'hv already done this.

Comment: can you give me the sdk link to download facebook graph api. may be i am using older one.