# Failed to login with facebook in my android app and getting error "param scope must be an array"

Tags: android, facebook-login

I am using Facebook login for my android application. But after inserting mail id and password in facebook login dialog page and press submit then it gives error "param scope must be an array".  please help me to resolve this error

Comment: Provide some code which you are trying?

Comment: please send me your email id i send my facebook login project

Answer (score 0):

Pass you facebook permission like below:

```
 List<String> fbPermissions = new ArrayList<String>();
    fbPermissions.add("user_likes");
    fbPermissions.add("email");
```

See Facebook Developer Guide for [Managing Permissions, Android](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/permissions)

You can see [Set permission for getting User's email ID from Facebook Login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16332283/set-permission-for-getting-users-email-id-from-facebook-login)

I hope its helps you.