# Graph api is not returning user email id

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

In this code GraphUser is not returning email-id and contact number.

```
 @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        if (state.isOpened()) {
            // userInfoTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                // Request user data and show the results
                Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                        if (user != null) {
                            // Display the parsed user info

                        String email=   (String) response.getGraphObject().getProperty("email");

                            System.out.println("yahooooooooooo  "+email);
                            buildUserInfoDisplay(user);
                        }
                    }
                });
        } else if (state.isClosed()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Logged out...");
        }
    }

    private String buildUserInfoDisplay(GraphUser user) {
        StringBuilder userInfo = new StringBuilder("");



        // Example: typed access (name)
        // - no special permissions required
        userInfo.append(String.format("Name: %s\n\n", 
            user.getName()));

        // Example: typed access (birthday)
        // - requires user_birthday permission
        userInfo.append(String.format("Birthday: %s\n\n", 
            user.getBirthday()));


        userInfo.append(String.format("Birthday: %s\n\n", 
                user.getBirthday()));


        userInfo.append(String.format("Gender: %s\n\n", 
                user.getProperty("gender")));

        userInfo.append(String.format("Iddddddd: %s\n\n", 
                user.getId()));
        // Example: partially typed access, to location field,
        // name key (location)
        // - requires user_location permission
        userInfo.append(String.format("Location: %s\n\n", 
            user.getLocation().getProperty("name")));

        // Example: access via property name (locale)
        // - no special permissions required
        userInfo.append(String.format("Locale: %s\n\n", 
            user.getProperty("locale")));
        return userInfo.toString();
    }
```

Comment: Do you have the `email` permission?

Comment: Sorry how to add the permission

Answer (score 9):

By default you won't get the email, for email you have to specify permission

```
Session.StatusCallback statusCallback = new Session.StatusCallback() 
        {

            @Override
            public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) 
            {
                if(session.isOpened())
                {
                    Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() 
                    {

                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) 
                        {

                            if(user != null)
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    System.out.println("Graph Inner Json"+user.getInnerJSONObject());
                                    String email = user.getInnerJSONObject().getString("email");
                                }
                             }
                         }
                     }
                 }
            }

YourActivityName.openActiveSession(this, true, statusCallback);
```

This is our `openActiveSession()` where we specify permissions

```
private static Session openActiveSession(Activity activity, boolean allowLoginUI, Session.StatusCallback statusCallback)
    {
        OpenRequest openRequest = new OpenRequest(activity);
        openRequest.setPermissions(Arrays.asList("user_birthday", "email"));
        openRequest.setCallback(statusCallback);

        Session session = new Session.Builder(activity).build();

        if(SessionState.CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED.equals(session.getState()) || allowLoginUI)
        {
            Session.setActiveSession(session);
            session.openForRead(openRequest);

            return session;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

and inside `onActivityResult()` don't forget to do

```
if(Session.getActiveSession() != null)
        {
            Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I got another situation where i was passing all the permissions but still getting error "No value for email". The reason behind this was that there was no primary email verified for that Facebook account (To see Primary Email in Facebook go to Account Settings--> Email).
So if there is no primary Email is verified for a Facebook account then you will always get this error. Please be sure that there is one verified primary Email for that Facebook account you are accessing.