# Facebook sdk 3.0 where set the permision?

Tags: android, email, facebook-sdk-3.0

my code work fine to get basic user information. But now I need the email of the user.
I need to set the permision "email" on the opened session. but i don't know where...
In open, ito don't work.
this is the full code of the activity

```
public class MainActivityFB extends Activity {

    TextView v;
    String FbToken; 

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.black);

    getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.color.actionbar));
    final List<String> PERMS =  new ArrayList<String>(); //= new String[] { "read_stream", "email" }; //set email permision. 

    // start Facebook Login
    Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

      // callback when session changes state

      @Override
      public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {

          PERMS.add("read_stream");
          PERMS.add("email");
          NewPermissionsRequest aa = new NewPermissionsRequest(MainActivityFB.this, PERMS);
          System.out.println("Chiamo la richiesta di permessi " + aa.toString());
          session.requestNewReadPermissions(aa); //this do nothings. no permision was called
        if (session.isOpened()) {

             System.out.println("session token " + session.getAccessToken());
             FbToken = session.getAccessToken();
          // make request to the /me API

          Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

            // callback after Graph API response with user object
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {

              if (user != null) {

               String nickname = user.getName();

                String id = user.getId();

            //user.getEmail()... not found

            //Do somethings, start the new activity...

            finish();

              }
            }
          });
        } else {
            //Session not open
        }


      }
    });
  }

  @Override
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

      Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
      Session session = Session.getActiveSession();


  }
```

where i have to set the new permission to read the email?
Thanks and sorry for my english

Comment: Check this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16332283/set-permission-for-getting-users-email-id-from-facebook-login

Comment: kindly check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/17082098/1939564

Answer (score 0):

Below is the complete response you get from the Response object in **onCompleted callback method**.
Check if response is not null (for safety), then you can parse the JSON response and get email id from it.

Permission "email" is valid as you have done here:

PERMS.add("read_stream");
PERMS.add("email");   // -- valid permission

As printed in log like this:
**Log.i("fb_response", response.toString());**

**{Response:  responseCode: 200, graphObject: GraphObject{graphObjectClass=GraphObject, state={"work":[{"employer":{"id":"some_number","name":"some_name"}}],"location":{"id":"some_id","name":"ab, cd"},"middle_name":"name","locale":"en_US","link":"https://www.facebook.com/link_to_your_profile","education":[{"type":"unknown","school":{"id":"some_id","name":"school_name"}}],"updated_time":"2013-07-31T09:01:15+0000","id":"some_id","first_name":"some_name","timezone":3.5,"username":"user_name","email":"myemailid@email.com","verified":true,"name":"name_in_full","last_name":"some_name","gender":"some_gender"}}, error: null, isFromCache:false}**

I have edited the values in the response.

Comment: thank's i now this. but the problem is where put "perms.add" and after where set the permision to the session

Comment: no need of email permission to read the user permission. Its Request.executeMeRequestAsync. Permission not required to read email.

Answer (score 0):

You can Set permission : Refer this [Graph api is not returning user email id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17081621/graph-api-is-not-returning-user-email-id/17082098#17082098)  And [Set permission for getting User's email ID from Facebook Login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16332283/set-permission-for-getting-users-email-id-from-facebook-login)

Enjoy Coding :)